# Problem with GNU GRUB and external HDD with ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, external-hdd

I have installed Ubuntu in an external HDD. To do so, I formatted the external Hard Disk to ext4 and mounting point /. Then, I used that partition as boot. Now, whenever the HDD is mounted, the system boots correctly. It gives me both ubuntu and windows options. The problem is that when I unmount the Hard Disk to automatically boot windows, the GNU GRUB window pops up and I have to type the "exit" command to boot windows. Is there a way of solving this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1Mpc.png)

I still don't understand why ubuntu is alongside with windows if I installed it separatelly

Thank you very much

Comment: Is this an EFI system?

Comment: I guess it should be. I do not remember changing this option BTW

Comment: So then when the machine starts it is expecting to find that physically both OS that are configured it its config file are present.

Comment: Sure! Wouldn't it be more clever to jump straigth to the next bootloader once one is not found? Is there a way to perform this?

Comment: You can change boot order in UEFI boot menu, often f12 but varies. You really need an ESP on your external drive. Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs grub to first drive, usually your internal drive. They do not want to fix this bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 You can just add the ESP - efi system partition FAT32 with boot,esp flags on external drive & reinstall grub. You can use Boot-Repair's advanced mode or chroot. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Then remove UEFI entry for Ubuntu that uses internal drive's ESP.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was exacly what I required. I have got a fully portable ubuntu now. Have a great day!!